# variable with interrogation point at the end

Tags: javascript

I have found an example and on this I have a variable with an interrogation point at the end

```
export class User {
    id: number;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    token?: string;
}
```

Someone know why token have a "?"

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is TypeScript, the question mark means "optional".

Comment: Ah ok ! Thanks a lot !